# Can Engine Lugging cause Piston Ring wear?

Tags: oil, wear, tuning

I just had my oil analyzed from my 2007 335i highly tuned car. I am using the Motul 300v 5w40 and everything seems really good, except for Chromium and Molybdenum. Before this, every value was fine with a different oil.

People are running much higher power than I do. My power level is pretty conservative on this platform.

I once let my friend drive my car, and he lugged the engine in 4th at around 1400rpm like twice. Is it possible it put so much side force on the pistons that it cause some piston ring wear?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What coolant do you use? If you have a small coolant leak which goes into the oil, this can cause Moly/Chrome levels to rise as well. Many coolants have both of these elements in them. I don't know if I'd put too much stock in the differences between the two oil samples, considering you used two different oils between. Oils can be hugely different in makeup and additives.

Comment: I think I have the OEM BMW coolant in my car, I have had my car for over a year now, but I haven't flushed the coolet yet, so not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe lugging it twice will be the cause, neither will blaming the change of oil.

Without comparison values going back over time so that the progression can be seen, if any...

One thing to consider is that a coating on a component is wearing differently, but you will need to watch this over time to see how it changes. It may be that these values stay relatively constant over the next several thousand miles.

Until you have data to show what is happening it is very difficult to draw conclusions, except for one:
 **drive your own car, let your friend drive his**...

Comment: Here is a previous oil lab results
[Liqui Moly 5w40](https://i.imgur.com/3CVoziH.jpg)

Comment: So, does your new oil have a molybdenum based additive to reduce wear?

Comment: It doesn't say on the box, I couldn't find it, but I think it is really possible because it is a race oil and meant to reduce wear as much as possible.